# iOS programatically know whether Profile is installed or not

Tags: ios, configuration, profile, utility

I am a beginner in iOS programming. I am building an app that lets the user download a Configuration Profile by simply opening a web page in safari. In the app, a label should show a certain message depending on whether the user has installed the profile or not. Can I know, programatically, whether a profile is installed or not?

Comment: so you're building a web app and not an Objective C or Swift app, right?  what language are you using?

Comment: No it is a native app, where there is a button that opens a URL in Safari. Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not have a way of knowing whether the profile is installed programmatically.